# How to scrape all the hotel reviews from HolidayIQ using Rvest and phantomJS

Tags: r, phantomjs, rvest, rselenium

I want to scrape all the user reviews from this [hotel main page](http://www.holidayiq.com/Taj-Exotica-Benaulim-hotel-2025.html), using the Rvest package in R.

I am only able to retrieve first 10 reviews. The next set of reviews is loaded by clicking the 'View more' button, which is generated by JavaScript.

I have written following JavaScript - 'basic.js':

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'taj.html'

page.open('http://www.holidayiq.com/Taj-Exotica-Benaulim-hotel-2025.html', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path,content,'w')
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Then, I have used following command in R:

```
system("./phantomjs basic.js")
```

The output 'taj.html' file does not have all the reviews. So, the scrape code...

```
pg <- read_html("taj.html")
pg %>% html_nodes(".detail-review-by-hotel .srm") %>% html_node(".media-heading") %>%   html_text()
```

... only returns the first 10 reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RSelenium:

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer() #just the first time
startServer()
startServer(invisible = FALSE, log = FALSE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                  , port = 4444
                  , browserName = "chrome"
)
remDr$open()
```

Navigate to your page

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.holidayiq.com/Taj-Exotica-Benaulim-hotel-2025.html")
```

Click the button "View more" until there is something to press (when it's done stop manually the execution)

```
while(TRUE){
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "#loadMoreTextReview")
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem) # move mouse to the element we selected
remDr$click(1) # 2 indicates click the right mouse button
}
```

Scrape everything you need using the css selector (with syntax similar to Rvest)

```
namesNodes <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', "#result-items .media-heading")
names<-unlist(lapply(namesNodes, function(x){x$getElementText()}))

firstCommentNodes <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".featured-blog-clicked") # the second element is the css selector
firstComment<-unlist(lapply(firstCommentNodes, function(x){x$getElementText()}))

reviewNodes <- remDr$findElements(using = 'css selector', ".detail-posted-txt p") # the second element is the css selector
review<-unlist(lapply(reviewNodes, function(x){x$getElementText()}))
```

I suggest reading the selector gadget vignette to understand how to select css path -> ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html

Comment: can you also show me the way to extract full review text (text after clicking the "read more" button)??